# Prolog infinite recursion not filling up the stack?

Tags: recursion, prolog, stack-overflow

Using the following example the stack quickly fills due to an infinite recursion...

```
is_pos_integer(X):- is_pos_integer(Y),X is Y+1.
is_pos_integer(0).
```

However, the following example when run and requested to backtrack (using ;), hits the same infinite recursion without filling up the stack...

```
is_pos_integer(0).
is_pos_integer(X):- is_pos_integer(Y),X is Y+1.
```

I don't believe either function is tail recursive, so why would the second one *not* cause a ........... StackOverflow? (yaaaaoww....*sunglasses*)

Comment: On what query and what Prolog system?

Comment: Yes, *neither example* is tail recursive! And: Tail call optimization only applies if *no choice points* remain! The first example also needs to keep track of choice points. Also, one more elementary note: It is typically much better to describe positive integers with your Prolog system's **CLP(FD)** constraints, for example: `positive_integer(I) :- I #> 0.`

Answer (score 2):

On the assumption that your query is something like `?- is_pos_integer(1)` then the explanation is this:

The first example just goes into an infinite loop not subject to tail-recursion. So the stack fills up.

The second example will also fill up, eventually, but very slowly.

Let's label the first clause A and second clause B. When you call the first version of `is_pos_integer(0)`, the call pattern is AAAAA... (out of stack). When you call the second version you get A (which returns to `true` to the top level) and then on backtracking BA which fails because 0 does not equal 0 + 1, then BBA which fail again because 0 does not equal 1 + 1, etc. You get call of BB...B(ntimes) and then A which fails. Eventually you will run out of stack, but it will take a very long time.